# Limit of sequence $a_n = (-4)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Using a calculator, I can see that this sequence $a_n = (-4)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$ is convergent and has limit -1. However, I am struggling to prove this in a formal way.

Since the exponent tends to zero when $n$ tends to infinity, I thought that the limit should be 1 (but this is not what I get using the calculator). Why is my reasoning wrong?

It would be very helpful if anyone could give me a hint as to how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $n=1$ for instance, how do you define $(-4)^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: I would say that is negative cubic root of 4.

Comment: As @Tuvasbien said, I think we have to be very careful with notation here. Exactly which roots do you take? Since there will be exactly ${2n-1}$ complex roots to the question ${a^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}}$. Now, if you take the principle roots, indeed we will get the limit ${1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your definition of $(-4)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$, we have
$$ (-4)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}=-4^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}=-e^{\frac{\ln 4}{2n+1}}=-1 $$
because $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{\ln 4}{2n+1}}=0$.

Comment: I know OP has defined it as ${(-4)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}=-(4)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}}$, but wouldn't usual notation define ${(-4)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}(4)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}}$?

Comment: The problem is that $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$ can take multiple values beyond the complex numbers. But the only real root of $-1$ is $-1$ since $(-1)^{2n+1}=-1$. The notation $(-1)^{1/3}$ is not used as far as i know because of this problem, which $1^{1/3}$ does not have.

Comment: Yeah true. The original question does have a bit of a notation problem

Answer (score 1):

It is $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(-4)^{1/(2n+1)}=1$$ since $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}=0$$